# How to know which transformer I need for electronic board?

Tags: transformer

I'm not an electronics guy, and I have limited knowledge about it.

I've bought an extremely old electro mechanical piano.

As I finally received it I realised that it needs a multi-voltage transformer. It is missing.

The piano doesn't have any kind of stickers or info.

I've spent days and days trying to look up for info or technical manual but I found nothing.

- How do I know which transformer I need?
- What are the voltages and amperes it should be?

Manufacturer name : columbia elepian
Model : EP-7
[image]

Comment: *i realised that it needs multi voltage transformer* - realized it how?

Comment: Name the manufacturer.  Name the model.  Post a picture.  You've basically asked "what size wrench do I need for this bolt" without showing it to us.  There's no way to tell.

Comment: What kind ? http://www.hallofelectricpianos.co.uk/epianos2.html

Comment: You might be more successful on vintage electric piano enthusiast forums. Here's one thread https://ep-forum.com/smf/index.php?topic=8901.0 (several years old).

Comment: If the transformer is missing, show the interface board details. The Roland equivalent EP-7 piano just needs 9Vdc with unknown Watts

Comment: We're not really equipped to answer -- we're more here to teach you enough EE so that _you_ can answer.  IMHO you really want to find an enthusiast forum that has people who know that brand of piano.  They'll help you find what you need, or someone will _have_ what you need, and when you run into the _next_ problem, they'll help you with that, too.